# Interpolation/smoothing in Mathematica using Graphics

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica, interpolation

I am trying to smooth the path I draw between points.

Please consider :

```
 lesPoints = {{41, 26}, {42, 29}, {41, 31}, {46, 30}, {48, 30}, 
              {40, 30}, {43, 30}, {47, 30}, {48, 26}, {47, 20}}
```

Those are the real eye fixations coordinates I use to trace the temporal path.

This is the way I plot them now :

```
Graphics[{
         Table[Arrow[{lesPoints[[i]], lesPoints[[i + 1]]}], 
              {i,Length[lesPoints] - 1}], 
         MapThread[Text[Style[#1, Large, FontFamily -> "Impact"], {#2, #3}] &, 
         PrependTo[Transpose[lesPoints], Range[1, Length@lesPoints]]]}]
```

[image]

**I could not get anything right in my attempt to use interpolation.**

**Would it be a good way to smooth the path, what would be an alternative ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about something like this

```
lesPoints = {{41, 26}, {42, 29}, {41, 31}, {46, 30}, {48, 30}, 
          {40, 30}, {43, 30}, {47, 30}, {48, 26}, {47, 20}}

interpolation = Interpolation[Table[{i, lesPoints[[i]]}, {i, Length[lesPoints]}]]
```

The path then becomes something like

```
plot = ParametricPlot[interpolation[t], {t, 1, Length[lesPoints]}];
Show[plot, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point /@ lesPoints}], Axes -> False]
```

Result:

[image: smooth curve]

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I leave it a bit open to see if other experts feel inspired but it solved my problemn!

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way:

```
Show[Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point /@ lesPoints}], 
     ListLinePlot[lesPoints, InterpolationOrder -> 4]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Also (easier)

```
ListLinePlot[lesPoints, InterpolationOrder -> 4, Mesh -> Full,  Axes -> None]
```

**Edit**

By using [**this beautiful package**](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~gianluca.gorni/Mma/Mma.html#CurvesGraphics) you can get:

```
Show[Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.015], Point /@ lesPoints}], 
 ListLinePlot[lesPoints, InterpolationOrder -> 4, Oriented     -> True, 
                                                  HowManyArrows -> 5]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

last one :)

```
Show[
  ListLinePlot[
     lesPoints, InterpolationOrder -> 4, 
     Epilog -> (MapIndexed[Inset[Style[Text@First@#2, Medium], #1 + {-.2, .4}] &, 
               lesPoints]), 
     PlotRangePadding -> 1, Oriented -> True, Axes -> False, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[.015]]], 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.008], Point /@ lesPoints}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @500 If you have the positions AND times, you could Animate the movement too!

Comment: Waow, thank You.I have the times and definitely want to implement those beautiful paths !  I must say I am puzzled right now, I think I need to modify the way I built my eye-movement analysis main program, I don`t use the Show Function and have everything in 1 big Graphics. And this is creating trouble I only solve temporally muting troubles when using some Plot Function. And here those bells are ringing again.

Comment: I uploaded the latest version of my notebook there : http://www.laeh500.com/LAEH/Mathematica.html . I left only the relevant part open where you will see the large Manipulate/Graphics. Please let me know if you have a chance to look if there is something obvious you think I should do or not do so as to use Plot as well as Graphics in a Manipulate. That would be of great help. I feel it is time to think efficiency a bit now for me :) Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @500 I downloaded your nb, but it is too large! Sorry, I don't have the time to read it (nor the ability to do it quickly). If you have some question regarding something in particular, I could try to check it if time permits.

Comment: Thank You. I will try to make the problem simple and ask you. This is one of the best benefit of this forum anyway ! Often, while abstracting a problem to ask a question I solve it on the way !

Comment: @500, I don't know if this helps, but ordinary 2D plot functions in Mathematica such as `ListLinePlot` (or `ParametricPlot` for that matter) produce something of the form `Graphics[{primitives}, options]` so if you don't want to create a separate plot for your curve and use Show (and looking at your file, I can see why :-)) you could put something like `ListLinePlot[...][[1]]` directly inside your `Graphics` to get the curved paths.

Comment: @Heike, Thank you for your attention ! I will try !